# nodejs: remove json element in json object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to remove a specific ID from the ids.json file I did everything but did not work I do not know where the problem is in my code

```
{
    "48515607821312": {
        "members": [
            "23422619525120",
            "2861007038851585",
            "515129977816704",
            "5151310082907392",
            "5158931505321230",
            "51590130345728"
        ]
    }
}
```

my script

```
var M = bot.ids[message.guild.id].members;
        var count = 0;
    M.forEach(function(id) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(id);
        delete bot.ids[id];  

        fs.writeFile('./ids.json', JSON.stringify(bot.ids, null, 4), err => {
         if(err) throw err;
     });  

      }, count * 5000)
      count++;
    });
```

Comment: Is there an error message? What's wrong? Where did said thing go wrong? What is supposed to happen? What is the actual outcome? Please reference this guide on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no i want delete one id every 5 sec from [0] to [5] and start with 23422619525120 and end with 51590130345728

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity with the test data, I have adjusted `var M = bot.ids[message.guild.id].members;` on line 1 of your script to pull directly from the sample array...

My solution would be:

```
/*
 * Sample Data
 */
var bot = {
    ids: {
        "48515607821312": {
            "members": [
                "23422619525120",
                "2861007038851585",
                "515129977816704",
                "5151310082907392",
                "5158931505321230",
                "51590130345728"
            ]
        }
    }
}

var botObj = bot.ids["48515607821312"] // Replace with bot.ids[message.guild.id] for application

/*
 * Loop Thru Members
 */
botObj.members.forEach((id, index) => {
    /*
     * Create a new array starting at the current index 
     * thru the end of the array to be used in timeout
     */
    var remainingMembers = botObj.members.slice(index, -1)
    /*
     * Define Timeout
     */
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(id)
        /*
         * Overwrite bot object with the remaining members
         */
        botObj.members = remainingMembers
        /*
         * Store updated JSON
         */
        fs.writeFile('./ids.json', JSON.stringify(bot.ids, null, 4), err => {
            if(err) throw err;
        });  
    }, index * 1000)
});
```

This uses the array index as a replacement for your `count` and defines the "remaining" array members for each timeout at the forEach execution instead of within the timeout.  This solution assumes that the members array will not have any new members added during the execution of the timeouts.

Comment: throw error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined and UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined i did try delete members code work but the code dose not delete the id form ids.json

Comment: The forEach and slice errors are depending on botObj.members...sounds like your modifications are triggering the errors you are encountering.